# Set html from 1 div to another using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 1 div and 1 text input field, the div is visible and the input is hidden. The input one gets its value from a range slider, I want to use jQuery somehow to take the value from this input area and populate the div on the fly, I've tried the following with no luck, can anybody see where i may be going wrong?

```
    $( ".value-slider" ).val(  $( "#val-slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
    $( ".price" ).html(  $( ".value-slider" ).html() );
```

Comment: can you post your html/slider code into http://jsfiddle.net, please. If the slider is a jquery plugin it will probably have an event attached that you can use to populate the hidden field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, `.value-slider` is an `input` element, and `.price` is a `div` element. If that's right, then you need to get the *value* of the input, rather than the HTML:

```
$( ".price" ).html(  $( ".value-slider" ).val() );
```

However, since you've just set the value of `.value-slider`, why not just store the value of the slider and use that?

```
var sliderValue = $( "#val-slider" ).slider( "value" ); 
$(".value-slider" ).val(sliderValue); 
$( ".price" ).html(sliderValue);
```

Comment: Thanks @James Allardice, is there a way to do it so whenever the input is changed, the .price div is automatically amended?

Comment: Below, I've posted the code that should automatically amend the price div if the input value changes. I borrowed code from James Allardice's answer.

Answer (score 0):

To update the `div` whenever the input changes, do this

```
    $(".value-slider" ).change(function() {
        var sliderValue = $( "#val-slider" ).slider( "value" ); 
        $(".value-slider" ).val(sliderValue); 
        $( ".price" ).html(sliderValue);
    });
```